# Collecting PII in an iframe on any website. Is it Safe?

Tags: web-browser, browser-extensions, iframe

I am building a chrome extension that allows users to submit a form on any website. Once a user would visit a certain website, extension would open iframe on that website and ask user for some PII in a form.

If website is malicious, can the website collect contents of the iframe, thus, stealing user's PII?